# curl downloads fail on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, bash, curl, osx-yosemite

Is there a problem with curl on OSX Yosemite? I have now experienced the same problem repeatedly on different combinations of local and remote networks (downloading different software from different locations). I'm running OSX 10.10.2. All attempts start alright, but after some time they all finish in one of the following error messages:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer  
curl: (56) Recv failure: Operation timed out
```

The reason I'm using curl for downloading is that curl is part of different install scripts. Ordinary downloads work fine, so I don't think there is an internet connection problem.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with ssh and rsync after upgrading to 10.10.2

Comment: I got problems with ports update, ssh, rsync, git push via https, all of them timing out quite often on two machines. But it seems Apple improved bluetooth audio so at least listening to music waiting for the timeouts is possible

Comment: I have Yosemite, and have no problems with Curl. Are you possibly behind a firewall? Do you have the environment variable `http_proxy` set?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be a complete solution but, you could try using wget instead.

Also the main curl syntax I use is:

```
curl -L 'http://example.com/file.txt' -o 'file.txt'
```

I am running OS X Yosemite too.

wget:

```
wget 'http://example.com/file.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

`Connection reset by peer` and `Operation timed out` usually mean that the server or file can't be reached. From the `libcurl` error codes list,

```
CURLE_RECV_ERROR (56)
    Failure with receiving network data.
```

Maybe you can try getting the same file from another server? If you're using `curl` in install scripts, maybe it's possible to submit a bug report? Since everything else in the network is working fine, I'll guess it's a problem with the installation script.